# Multiple background images in one div

Tags: html, css

I made a ribbon in Photoshop. The ribbon has three part. The left and right parts are a fixed 10px. The middle sectoin is a repeatable pattern.

Is it possible to combine these images as the background of my  tag?

Comment: Only in CSS3 can you have multiple backgrounds for an element, so yes, but not all browsers would support it.

Comment: Here's another possible solution for the issue. If you can change the background so it's made up of two images you can use the technique explained here: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/slidingdoors2/

Answer (score 25):

As @j08691 pointed out, this is only possible in CSS3

```
#your-selector {
  background-image: url(one.png), url(two.png);
  background-position: center bottom, left top;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 300px;
  height: 350px;
}
```

See [**tutorial**](http://www.css3.info/preview/multiple-backgrounds/)

Comment: Good Solution.  But, from what I read, does not work in all browsers... in my mind, is widespread enough to use, but depends on your target audience.  Use with caution.

Answer (score 3):

Just add a class to the tag, then using CSS add the background to that class. This will not work on IE8 or earlier

```
div
{ 
background:url(smiley.gif) top left no-repeat,
url(sqorange.gif) bottom left no-repeat,
url(sqgreen.gif) bottom right no-repeat;
}
```

Code is from http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background.asp

To get it to work in other versions of IE you can use something like CSS3Pie http://css3pie.com/documentation/supported-css3-features/#pie-background
However I would test thoroughly before putting the code live

Answer (score 0):

It is only possible with css3 for modern browsers.

```
.element{
    background-image: url(key.png), url(stone.png);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although not all browsers support it, but it is possible with CSS3.
It should look like this:

```
#example1 {
background-image: url(img_flwr.gif), url(paper.gif);
background-position: right bottom, left top;
background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat;
}
```

You can see other examples [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_backgrounds.asp).

Comment: Is there any need to answer a six years old question with a nearly copied answer that was already given six years ago?