# Image doesn't show up like it should

Tags: html, css

Cause of my job i have to learn html and CSS.
And so it happend pretty fast that i got a problem i can't find a solution for.

This CSS:

```
#footer{
    height: 207px;
    margin-top: 7px;
    background: url(img/footer.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#footer.menue{
    height: 25px;
    background-image: url(img/menue.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

should bring two images to the website but onle the first one is shown.

HTML

```js
        <div id="footer">
            <ul class="menue">
                <li><a href="#Links">Links</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Kontakt">Kontakt</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Impressum">Impressum</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

[solved:]
http://jsbin.com/utupat/1/edit

Comment: Can you post your HTML mark-up?

Comment: Can you provide a live link of this site?  Syntax wise you don't have any errors in your code.  Seems likely that you have a typo in your file name or something like that.  One that gets me pretty often when working with other peoples images is if JPG is capitalized.  If it is then it will not work. It's all case sensitive.

Comment: checked the typo countless times i even copied the name out of the directory

Answer (score 0):

If you are using html code:

```
<div id="footer" class="menue"></div>
```

and css as

```
#footer{
    height: 207px;
    margin-top: 7px;
    background: url(img/footer.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#footer.menue{
    height: 25px;
    background-image: url(img/menue.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat; }
```

U are using same height for one div, he will use second one - 25px and disrigard first one. Also you can not have 2 background images one one div, he will use just one. If u want multiple background images, you have to use css3 feature [Multiple background images in one div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9070362/multiple-background-images-in-one-div)