# Align 2 images in background in a div

Tags: css, background-image

I would like to put 2 images as background image inside a div.

This is the code i put but i see only the second image.

```css
#wrap-header {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  background-image: url("../assets/header_background.png"), url("../assets/circle_header_background.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center bottom, center top;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap-header">

</div>
```

I want to retrieve the effect of the one image under the other, or one image as first layer and the second up at the bottom.

I can't find a way. Could you pease help me ?

Comment: Is there any transparency in your image? Can you show us what the images look like? If the images are opaque, there is no one way image can be shown through another.

Comment: @BobRodes That is why I asked for the images. There are too many uncertainties/variables in OP's question that we actually have no idea what OP wants to achieve, and using what kind of images.

Comment: Your code snippet will have to put the full url if you want the images to show here.

Comment: @Terry Sorry Terry, I deleted my comment when I realized what you are saying. Of course you are right.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple background images in one div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9070362/multiple-background-images-in-one-div)

Comment: you can see the repository on my Github at https://github.com/mirkocoppola80/ct-web-page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do it with the `background-size: 100% 50%` where the first *value* of `100%` indicates the *width* of the *image*, and the second one its *height*, which is set to `50%` or always half of the `#wrap-header`'s `height`:

```css
#wrap-header {
  /*max-width: 100%; by default*/
  height: 400px;
  background-image: url('https://placeimg.com/1600/200/any'), url('https://placeimg.com/1600/201/any');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: bottom, top;
  background-size: 100% 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap-header"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using the CSS selectors **:after** and **:before**

First, add the following to #wrap-header:

```
#wrap-header {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
}
```

And then use the selectors:

```
#wrap-header:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url('image1');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center
}

#wrap-header:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url('image2');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with a help of pseudo elements :before and :after

```css
#wrap-header {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}

#wrap-header:before {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url("https://boutiqueme.com/static/4/generated/30-pattern-44-ff81c0.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}

#wrap-header:after {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/04/12/00/04/hero-1323464_960_720.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap-header">

</div>
```

Comment: Now it works. I forgot a question. How can i make background images responsive? Because i see that when i resize the screen the images are cut.

Comment: background-size property should help you on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:before` and `:after` `pseudo` selector to achive this

```css
/* Set #wrap-header to relative so that :before and :after does not goes outside */
#wrap-header {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
}

#wrap-header:before,
#wrap-header:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
}

/* Set First Background Image */
#wrap-header:before {
  background: url("http://via.placeholder.com/850x450") center bottom no-repeat;
}

/* Set Second Background Image */
#wrap-header:after {
  background: url("http://via.placeholder.com/900x450") center top no-repeat;  
  opacity: 0.3; /* Set transparency as per your requirement */
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap-header">

</div>
```